# JavaScript short circuit evaluation error?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator, typeof, short-circuiting

The two below snippets of JS code have had me confused, in my eyes both should work the same, due to short circuit evaluation. But for some reason snippet '1' causes the error (on the third line):

*Cannot read property 'match' of undefined*

Array 'a' holds 3 character values user entered into inputs. I want the code to return true if the char is undefined, an empty string, or a letter or number.

To be clear, this fails when a = ['a', '/'];

Snippet 1)

```
return typeof a[0] === 'undefined' || a[0] === '' || a[0].match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i) 
    && typeof a[1] === 'undefined' || a[1] === '' || a[1].match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i) 
    && typeof a[2] === 'undefined' || a[2] === '' || a[2].match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i);
```

Snippet 2)

```
if (typeof a[0] === 'undefined' || a[0] === '' || a[0].match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i)) {
    if (typeof a[1] === 'undefined' || a[1] === '' || a[1].match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i)) {
        if (typeof a[2] === 'undefined' || a[2] === '' || a[2].match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i)) {
            return true;           
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
return false;
```

Surely a[2].match should never be evaluated if a[2] is undefined due to the first conditional in the 'if'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple. Take a look to the [order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) .
AND binds more than OR.

In your Snippet 1 the expression is like:

```
a1 || b1 || (c1 && a2) || b2 || (c2 && a3) || b3 || c3
```

Your Snippet 2 is like:

```
(a1 || b1 || c1) && (a2 || b2 || c2) && (a3 || b3 || c3)
```

Comment: In  your answer is a1 == a[0]? and b1 ==  a[1]?

Comment: No, in me answer a1 is   "typeof a[0] === 'undefined' " and b1 is "a[0] === '' "

Answer (score 1):

@Christoph is right but you also need to add something like !== null after match like

```
return (typeof a[0] === 'undefined' || a[0] === '' || a[0].match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i) !==null )  && (typeof a[1] === 'undefined' || a[1] === '' || a[1].match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i) !== null ) && (typeof a[2] === 'undefined' || a[2] === '' || a[2].match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i) !== null);
```

You can take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dv360q1p/1/ which implements your question

Comment: Surely if a[0] is undefined it wouldn't evaluate 
 a[0].match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i) !==null
right?

Comment: Normally it won't. When you have multiple OR when you hit a first true condition there is no need to continue evaluating the rest of expressions. As well as for AND when you get the first false you can stop.